# Castle Windsor - How to create an installer to deal with multi level dependency structures

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a case where several different classes inherit from the same interface. Additionally, sometimes a class that inherits from the interface, also takes it as a dependency.

My solution looks like this:

```
InterfaceAssembly
    -IGetData<T>

DataAssembly
    -Repository.CustomerRepository : IGetData<Customer>
    -Repository.ProductRepository : IGetData<Product>
    -Cache.CustomerCache : IGetData<Customer>
    -Cache.ProductCache : IGetData<Product>
```

I would like to make an installer that prioritizes the `Cache` namespace over `Repository` name space. However, in the case of `CustomerCache`, it both implements, and has a dependency on `IGetData<Customer>`. `CustomerCache` should be injected with `CustomerRepository` to satisfy this dependency.

Is there a easy way to deal with this type of situation with Castle Windsor? Will I have to take special care to avoid an error from what it might deem a circular reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Decorator pattern. Castle recognizes decorators when registered in a right order. For instance when registered like:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IGetData<Customer>>().ImplementedBy<CustomerCache>());
container.Register(Component.For<IGetData<Customer>>().ImplementedBy<CustomerRepository>());
```

Then resolving `IGetData<Customer>` will return `CustomerCache` which decorates `CustomerRepository`.

Comment: Did a quick edit to fix the reversed order. Also, so far, Castle Windsor seems smart enough to figure this out, even with out explicitly ordering them correctly :)

Comment: You can also use `IsDefault()` when registering by convention. https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/aa9b8b353ee2e533d586495eec254e216f800c09/docs/whats-new-3.0.md#component-can-now-force-being-default-for-its-services-without-needing-to-be-the-first-one-registered